# WatchKit Table page scrolling

Tags: uitableview, scroll, watchkit

I don't know if this is possible at the moment but is there a way to scroll the watchkit Table page style similar to the page scroll on the iPhone TableView.

Or if not is is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

By page style I am assuming you mean horizontal scrolling page by page.  In WatchKit there is only one way to do horizontal page based scrolling.  You have to set up a page based UI.  You will have to have a new instance of a controller for each page.  See http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-page-based-navigation/ for more info.

Comment: And to extend @Stephen's answer. You can not have page-based hierarchy into a force-tap navigation or vice versa.